# Calculate process's running time

Tags: java

I want to calculate the running time of the process running on the task manager in windows.

If the particular process run after certain time than i can end that process.

Comment: I want to go to the moon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a story and not a question.

Comment: This is not a question but requirement of a feature. Try to search for a solution on the web. If you have specific problem. Question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the time functions.

```
//Your start time.
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//YOUR CALL GOES HERE

//Your end time. 
long stopTime = System.nanoTime();

//Take the difference and that is how long it takes to execute your function.
System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but in the future try to avoid answering a questions that don't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem and don't show any efforts.

Comment: ill try to but these question sometimes just get the best of me lol

Comment: Or if you DO want to answer, answer with explanations of the concepts. That way OP still has to work to get some working code.

Comment: This works only in single threaded case.

Comment: well if it its not single threaded the OP should have said that in a question.